# Send POST request to OData service using SAP Cloud SDK version 3.2.0

Tags: java, odata, sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk

I'm developing an application that uses **SAP Cloud SDK**. I was previously using **version 2.20.1** of **SAP Cloud SDK** and sent a **POST request** to an **OData service**. This is the code I used to send the **POST request**:

```
final ODataCreateRequestImpl createRequest =
            new ODataCreateRequestImpl("/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZAS_BP_CREATION_SRV",
                    "BP_DATASet", bodyAsMap, null, null, null, headersAsMap, null, false, null, null, false);

    JSONObject jsonResponse = null;

    try {

        Map<String, Object> resp = createRequest.execute("ErpQueryEndpoint").asMap();
        jsonResponse = new JSONObject(resp);

    } catch(final ODataException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    catch(final JSONException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

After updating the version of SAP Cloud SDK to 3.2.0, I get the following error when sending the POST request:

> Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.HttpClientAccessor.getHttpClient(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/http/client/HttpClient;

I know the reason for the **NoSuchMethodError**, the error occurs when calling the **execute** method of the **ODataCreateRequestImpl** class, this class is in **com.sap.cloud.servicesdk:odatav2-connectivity:1.32.5.jar**, and at some point, when calling to the **execute** method of the **ODataCreateRequestImpl** class, the **getHttpClient** method of the **HttpClientAccessor** class that belongs to **com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:cloudplatform-connectivity:3.2.0.jar** is called, within this class, the method signature is `public static HttpClient getHttpClient(@Nonnull HttpDestinationProperties destination)`, but the error I get is because the signature of this method at runtime is different, it expects to receive a **String** parameter instead of **HttpDestinationProperties**.

I think this is because I should not be using the **ODataCreateRequestImpl** class to execute a **POST** request in **version 3.2.0** of **SAP Cloud SDK**, although it did work perfectly in **version 2.20.1**. To migrate from **version 2.20.1** of **SAP Cloud SDK** to **version 3.2.0** I followed these guidelines:

https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/s4sdk-migration-v3.html

https://blogs.sap.com/2019/08/01/migrate-to-version-3.0.0-of-the-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java/

Could someone help me find a solution to be able to execute the POST request to the OData service?

This is the content of my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.atlantida.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>account</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>atlantida</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <springframework.version>5.1.8.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <jackson-version>2.9.2</jackson-version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.8</lombok.version>

        <jcl.slf4j.version>1.7.12</jcl.slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>

        <!-- if you are behind a proxy use the following two properties to configure your proxy. Default: None -->
        <proxy.host />
        <proxy.port />
        <non.proxy.hosts />

        <!-- Properties that are related to the SAP Cloud Platform. -->
        <scp.sdkVersion>1.44.12</scp.sdkVersion>

        <!-- this is the location of your local SAP CP Neo runtime -->
        <scp.sdkInstallPath>${project.basedir}/scp/sdk-${scp.sdkVersion}</scp.sdkInstallPath>
        <scp.sdkLocalServerContentPath>${project.basedir}/localServerContent</scp.sdkLocalServerContentPath>
        <scp.sdkErpEndpoint>${scp.sdkInstallPath}/server/config_master/service.destinations/destinations/ErpQueryEndpoint</scp.sdkErpEndpoint>

        <scp.sdkSymbolicLink>${project.basedir}/scp/sdk</scp.sdkSymbolicLink>
        <scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>.sh</scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>
        <scp.sdkNeoCmd>${scp.sdkInstallPath}/tools/neo${scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension}</scp.sdkNeoCmd>
        <scp.sdkLocalServer>${scp.sdkInstallPath}/server</scp.sdkLocalServer>

        <scp.skipInstallSdk>false</scp.skipInstallSdk>
        <scp.skipDeploy>false</scp.skipDeploy>
        <scp.skipPutDestination>false</scp.skipPutDestination>
        <scp.skipRestart>false</scp.skipRestart>
        <scp.skipRollingUpdate>true</scp.skipRollingUpdate>

        <scp.vmArguments />
        <scp.vmSize>lite</scp.vmSize>
        <scp.vmMinProcesses>1</scp.vmMinProcesses>
        <scp.vmMaxProcesses>1</scp.vmMaxProcesses>

        <scp.app />
        <scp.host />
        <scp.account />
        <scp.username />
        <scp.password />

        <!-- Required for SAP CP user session management and audit logging. -->
        <scp.warImportPackage>com.sap.security.auth.service,com.sap.security.um.service.api,com.sap.core.service.auditlog.impl,com.sap.cloud.auditlog,com.sap.cloud.auditlog.exception,com.sap.cloud.auditlog.extension</scp.warImportPackage>

        <!-- Defines whether the deployment is productive or not. -->
        <productive />
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bridge logging from JCL to SLF4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--&lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjtools &ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>1.6.2</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>scp-neo</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana</groupId>
            <artifactId>s4hana-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>security-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo-javaee7-wp-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>atlantida</finalName>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>SAP Cloud SDK Project Structure Checks</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>enforce</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <rules>
                                    <requireMavenVersion>
                                        <version>3.5</version>
                                    </requireMavenVersion>
                                    <requireJavaVersion>
                                        <version>${java.version}</version>
                                    </requireJavaVersion>
                                    <reactorModuleConvergence />
                                </rules>
                                <fail>true</fail>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                        <archive>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Version>${project.version}</Version>
                                <Import-Package>${scp.warImportPackage}</Import-Package>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                        <webResources>
                            <resources>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/web.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resources>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.sap.cloud</groupId>
                                <artifactId>neo-javaee7-wp-sdk</artifactId>
                                <version>${scp.sdkVersion}</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${scp.sdkInstallPath}</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Plugin for deployment to SAP Cloud Platform Neo. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.sap.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>neo-javaee7-wp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${scp.sdkVersion}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>stop</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>${scp.skipRestart}</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>deploy</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>${scp.skipDeploy}</skip>
                                <vmArguments>${scp.vmArguments}</vmArguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>start</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>${scp.skipRestart}</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>rolling-update</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>rolling-update</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>${scp.skipRollingUpdate}</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <sdkInstallPath>${scp.sdkInstallPath}</sdkInstallPath>
                        <skip>${scp.skipInstallSdk}</skip>

                        <application>${scp.app}</application>
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</source>

                        <vmArguments>${scp.vmArguments}</vmArguments>
                        <size>${scp.vmSize}</size>
                        <minimumProcesses>${scp.vmMinProcesses}</minimumProcesses>
                        <maximumProcesses>${scp.vmMaxProcesses}</maximumProcesses>

                        <host>${scp.host}</host>
                        <account>${scp.account}</account>
                        <user>${scp.username}</user>
                        <password>${scp.password}</password>
                        <synchronous>true</synchronous>

                        <httpProxyHost>${proxy.host}</httpProxyHost>
                        <httpProxyPort>${proxy.port}</httpProxyPort>
                        <httpsProxyHost>${proxy.host}</httpsProxyHost>
                        <httpsProxyPort>${proxy.port}</httpsProxyPort>

                        <consoleCommand />
                        <consoleHttpProxyHost>${proxy.host}</consoleHttpProxyHost>
                        <consoleHttpProxyPort>${proxy.port}</consoleHttpProxyPort>
                        <consoleHttpsProxyHost>${proxy.host}</consoleHttpsProxyHost>
                        <consoleHttpsProxyPort>${proxy.port}</consoleHttpsProxyPort>

                        <dbsystem />
                        <dbSize />
                        <dbUser />
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Plugin for deployment to local runtime of SAP Cloud Platform Neo. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scp-neo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <sdkPlugin>neo-javaee7-wp-maven-plugin</sdkPlugin>
                        <sdkPluginVersion>${scp.sdkVersion}</sdkPluginVersion>
                        <sdkInstallPath>${scp.sdkInstallPath}</sdkInstallPath>
                        <sdkSymbolicLink>${scp.sdkSymbolicLink}</sdkSymbolicLink>
                        <sdkServerContentPath>${scp.sdkLocalServerContentPath}</sdkServerContentPath>
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</source>
                        <proxyHost>${proxy.host}</proxyHost>
                        <proxyPort>${proxy.port}</proxyPort>
                        <httpNonProxyHosts>${non.proxy.hosts}</httpNonProxyHosts>
                        <destinations>
                            <destination>
                                <path>${scp.sdkErpEndpoint}</path>
                                <username>achacon</username>
                                <password>achacon100</password>
                                <url>http://sapcrmdev.adbancat.hn:8000</url>
                            </destination>
                        </destinations>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>usage-analytics-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>usage-analytics</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipUsageAnalytics>false</skipUsageAnalytics>
                            <generateSalt>true</generateSalt>
                                <!--
                                Note: A random salt is auto-generated once the project is built for the first time.
                                Please keep the generated salt in the POM file, for example, when pushing to git.

                                To learn more, visit: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/10/23/usage-analytics-s4sdk/
                                -->
                            <salt>5d5e4e1e8a5f05d547fe8880f65173bda150a670f91f3657b970eaa9e7a4d392</salt>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <!--
        Profiles that are used to set the Neo SDK "neo" command extension ("neo.sh" or "neo.cmd")
        -->
        <profile>
            <id>windows</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>.bat</scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>unix</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>unix</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>.sh</scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <!-- Profile setting properties for deploying to the local SAP CP runtime. -->
        <profile>
            <id>local-deploy</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>!scp.app</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <scp.skipInstallSdk>true</scp.skipInstallSdk>
                <scp.skipDeploy>true</scp.skipDeploy>
                <scp.skipPutDestination>true</scp.skipPutDestination>
                <scp.skipRestart>true</scp.skipRestart>
                <scp.skipRollingUpdate>true</scp.skipRollingUpdate>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <!-- Profile setting properties for deploying a productive version to SAP CP. -->
        <profile>
            <id>scp-deploy</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>productive</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <scp.skipInstallSdk>false</scp.skipInstallSdk>
                <scp.skipDeploy>true</scp.skipDeploy>
                <scp.skipPutDestination>false</scp.skipPutDestination>
                <scp.skipRestart>true</scp.skipRestart>
                <scp.skipRollingUpdate>false</scp.skipRollingUpdate>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There basically two ways how you can resolve the issue:

1. Create your own OData VDM via our Maven Plugin. That way you get typesafe access to the service and don't need to bother with the Strings in your request. For a rough guideline you could follow [this guide](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/30/deep-dive-10-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-generating-java-vdm-for-s4hana-custom-odata-service/), but be aware that it was written for version 2 of the SDK. We are in the process of updating our blog posts for version 3, but for the moment you would have to migrate it yourself (shouldn't be much more then changing the groupId and artifactId).
2. Use the `execute(HttpClient)` method instead, e.g. that way:

   ```java
   // altenative to create a Destination at runtime:
   // HttpDestination destination = DefaultHttpDestination.builder("https://www.google.de").build();
   HttpDestination destination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("ErpQueryEndpoint").asHttp();
   HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientAccessor.getHttpClient(destination);
   Map<String, Object> resp = createRequest.execute(httpClient).asMap();
   ```

   This should go through without a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, Schubert. I tried the second option you indicated, however, I get the same error **(NoSuchMethodError)** for the same reason. Is it possible to try the first option you indicated in your answer if I want to access an **SAP CRM** instead of **S/4HANA**?

Comment: Hm, okay. I just ran your pom file and code locally, once as provided (resulted in the reported NoSuchMethodError) and with my proposed changes. The changes resulted in errors due to a missing Neo runtime, which is to be expected (as I ran it locally without any Neo setup). Can you double check what the new error is you get? Or better: what class/method cannot be found? Also, I provided an update to my code snippet to show you how to create your "own" Destination which might make testing easier.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried the code snippet you provided and the code works perfectly. I was able to send the request to the OData service. I am very grateful that you and Alexander have taken the time to help me.

Comment: Glad to hear! Oh, and I forgot to answer your second question: we aim for compatibility with any OData service, so as long as you can retrieve the metadata file you can use the generator to create a typed VDM.

Answer (score 1):

A well documented question! Unfortunately it seems like the the attached version of *Service SDK* (`com.sap.cloud.servicesdk.*`) in *Cloud SDK* (`com.sap.cloud.sdk.*`)  has some internal dependency compatibility issues that was not tracked previously.

**Solution:**
Instead of *Cloud SDK* version `3.2.0`, please try version `3.9.0` (or later). The problem was fixed in that update. Don't worry about the jump in the version number. I wouldn't expect compatibility issues with your application code.

Alternatively, if you definitely want to stay with version `3.2.0`, then you could manually add a compatible *Service SDK* dependency version in your POM, e.g. `1.35.2` (or later).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Alex. Unfortunately, changing the versions the same happens, from the ODataCreateRequestImpl class the getHttpClient method of the HttpClientAccessor class is called by passing the destinationName parameter as String, but in the HttpClientAccessor class the getHttpClient method receives a destination parameter as HttpDestinationProperties and not as String. I also tried changing the version of SAP Cloud SDK to 3.9.0.
https://i.imgur.com/G5xr8xh.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/rWwkCEa.jpg